# Hidden Interface configuration?

Tags: networking, ethernet, interface

During installation of Ubuntu server 13.04, I configured the primary ethernet interface. This interface is visible in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

The system has two additional interfaces which I do not have configured. Nothing in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

When I do `ifconfig`, I see all three ethernet interfaces. The one which I have configured during the installation process and this is part of `/etc/network/interfaces` and the two other ethernet interfaces. These two other interfaces are configured with dhcp.

Who has configured these interfaces? Ubuntu?
What will happen when I will edit these two interfaces in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file? 
I only uses the commandline, no GUI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like network-manager is managing your interfaces. You should probably uninstall it if you don't want that to happen: `sudo apt-get remove network-manager`. Or maybe disable it so that if something goes wrong you can reactivate it (you can see how to disable it on the link below, section "Disabling NetworkManager"). Or you could comment everything in `/etc/network/interfaces` and try to configure everything using NetworkManager (there's the `nmcli` cli tool).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Comment: I disabled network manager and the non-configured interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces are gone. One question about network manager - in which file does network manager store the configuration? Is there a configuration file of the network manager?

Comment: The documentation says that all configuration are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager` and `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directories (including user defined settings). But in my system there's not many relevant files there... probably I'm just using default settings for almost everything.